# How to store sqlite3 db file inside binary

Tags: sqlite, go, packr

**What I want to do**:

I am developing a CLI app which has a read-only database (sqlite using `mattn/sqlite3`) which should not be exposed and the binary is just an API over the read-only database.

I tried tools like `packr` but it gives `File`, `string` or `[]byte{}` and the `sqlx.Connect` requires file path only

This [statckoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326215/how-to-bundle-an-sqlite-database-in-a-go-binary) talks about using `tempfile` but that too stays on FS.
I can't keep the DB file on FS as it can be accessed by anyone with access to the system.

**What I have already tried**

Keeping an encrypted file in storage and then decrypting it runtime and then storing it in sqlite `in-memory db` but when using multiple go-routines I'm facing a lot of issues like `table not found` which are already there on [GH issues](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/204) for `mattn/sqlite3` repo and are unsolved. So, I can't work with in-memory database.

Comment: Try the special file name ? https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: Already tried - doesn't go well with concurrent access from go routines

Comment: If that "not going well with multiple go routines" would be a general issue, hardly anyone would use it, would they. Presumably, it does not do well with *your* code - hence you might want to show us what you did so far.

Comment: In general: If you hand out the binary, [it is rather easy to extract payload](https://rednaga.io/2016/09/21/reversing_go_binaries_like_a_pro/). If the data can not be leaked: connect to a cloud instance (preferably via a REST API).

Comment: I'm fairly confident that the sqlite API allows reading from memory. That just apparently isn't exposed in the Go driver layer. It may be possible to add that feature to the Go package.